# Prove that $\int_{a}^b f + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} = bf(b) - af(a)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $0<a<b$ and $f>0$ be continous and strictly increasing on $[a,b]$. Prove that $\int_{a}^b f + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} = bf(b) - af(a)$.

since $f$ is an increasing function and $[a,b]$ is compact so $f$ attains its maximum and minimum at point $b$ and $a$ respectively i.e $f(a) \leq f(x)\leq f(b)$ so $\int_{a}^{b} f(a) \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(b)$ we get $f(a)(b-a) \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \leq f(b)(b-a)$.

Since $f$ is increasing so $f^{-1}$ is also increasing and with the similar reasoning we get $a(f(b)-f(a)) \leq \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}\leq b(f(b)-f(a))$

After adding them up I can't squeeze $\int_{a}^b f + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}$

Comment: **Hint :** Riemann sums may be useful.

Comment: Even easier: I'd strongly suggest just drawing a picture of such a function, and thinking about how to represent these two integrals as areas in that picture. (Also, thinking about inequalities seldom buys you much when you are trying to prove an exact equality, unless you can bound on both sides by the same quantity.)

Comment: @NickPeterson Thanks I got it

Comment: Please do not delete a question as soon as you get an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, disrespectful to people who might find the answer useful in the future.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I got to know that the question was repeated that's why

Comment: @lucas If you see that a question is a duplicate, then you should flag it as such.  Duplicate Q&As are often kept on the site as signposts for future readers.  If you can provide a link to the duplicate question, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[image]

---

Source: *Calculus*, Fourth Edition, of Michael Spivak.